# Tensorflow: How can I use tf.roll without wrapping?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to independently shift the columns or rows of a 2-D tensor like:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
shift = tf.constant([2, -1])
b = shift_fn(a, shift)
```

which gives me:

```
b = [[0, 0, 1], [5, 6, 0]]
```

I find that `tf.roll()` can do similar things but will wrap the elements. How can I pad zeros using it?

Comment: To clarify, you want a cyclic shift of every row (or column) independently?

Comment: No, for every row or column, there is a specified shift. But I don't want it to be cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

One *not-so-nice* solution is to first pad the tensor using [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad), then use [`tf.roll`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/roll) inside [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to independently shift each row (or column) of the padded tensor. And then finally, you can take the proper slice of the result. For example:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
shift = tf.constant([2, -1])

cols = a.shape[1]
paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [cols, cols]])
padded_a = tf.pad(a, paddings)

tf.map_fn(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], x[1], axis=-1),
    elems=(padded_a, shift),
    # The following argument is required here
    fn_output_signature=a.dtype
)[:,cols:cols*2]

"""
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [5, 6, 0]], dtype=int32)>
"""
```

Alternatively, to help save some memory, both padding and slicing could be done inside the `fn` function passed to `tf.map_fn`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@tf.function
def shift(inputs, shift, axes, pad_val = 0):
    assert len(shift) == len(axes)
    axis_shift = zip(axes, shift)
    axis2shift = dict(axis_shift)  
    old_shape = inputs.shape

    for axis in axis2shift:
        pad_shape = list(inputs.shape)
        pad_shape[axis] = abs(axis2shift[axis])
        input_pad = tf.fill(pad_shape, pad_val)
        inputs = tf.concat((inputs, input_pad), axis = axis) 
    
    
    input_roll = tf.roll(inputs, shift, axes)
    ret = tf.slice(input_roll, [0 for _ in range(len(old_shape))], old_shape)

    return ret
```

The above function implements shift with tf.roll like interface* (shift and axes are expected to be lists rather than tensors). As told by @today in a previous answer, I performed the pad-roll-slice operation.

Hope this helps